# .NET stream writer Variable format

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, streamwriter, string.format

I'm trying to write a CSV file with a variable output format.

The code is

```
fs.WriteLine(String.Format(format,
                             data(0),
                             data(1),
                             data(2),
                             data(3),
                             data(4),
                             data(5)
                           )
            )
```

this works,
However if i'm trying to pass the same argument

```
 data(0),
 data(1),
 data(2),
 data(3),
 data(4),
 data(5)
```

in a string

```
str = "data(3)  , data(2)  , data(1)  , data(0)"
fs.WriteLine(String.Format(format, str))
```

I get an error

> Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Because in the second call you are passing two parameters to method. But in the first one you are passing 6 parameters. And string.format treat each parameter as separate variable in the `format` string

Comment: why would you want to do that anyway?

Answer (score 4):

This is a literal string:

```
str = "data(3)  , data(2)  , data(1)  , data(0)"
```

what you want is a String Array like this:

```
str = {data(3), data(2), data(1), data(0)}
```

Note: You will have to change your declaration of `str` from being a String to being a String Array as well from:

```
Dim str As String
```

to

```
Dim str As String()
```

However

If you just have a bunch of variables to write out into a CSV you can do this more easily like this:

```
    Using sr As New StreamWriter(filename)
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder
        For Each value In data
            sb.Append(value & ",")
        Next
        sr.WriteLine(sb.ToString.TrimEnd(","c))
    End Using
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to write those data elements out in the order of:

```
 `data(3), data(2), data(1), data(0)`
```

Then your format argument should be:

```
format = "{3}, {2}, {1}, {0}"
' when used:

fs.WriteLine(String.Format(format,
                         data(0),
                         data(1),
                         data(2),
                         data(3),
                         data(4),
                         data(5)
                       )
        )
```

This would write out whatever is passed as the 4th argument (`data(3)`) as the first item in outout.  The second item in the output will be the 3rd argument or `data(2)`.

---

Based on your previous question, it looks like you are trying to change/manage the order of both the placeholders in `format` **and** the order that the `data()` elements are specified.  That wont work and you do not need to.

Since both the placeholders in the format string and the data array are zero based, `{0}` => `data(0)`, `{1}` => `data(1)` and so forth.  So all you ever need to do is change the order of the `{n}` placeholder in the format string.  Leave the `data(n)` designations and order alone.

This [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dL7GtX) demonstrates the concept.  The data items stay in the same order, just use a different format string as needed.

Comment: Just because I love string interpolation in the new language versions: `sf.WriteLine($"{data(3)}, {data(2)}, {data(1)}, {data(0)}")`.

Comment: but s/he needs to write the data out in a different order each time.  there is a fair amount the OP didnt make clear here

Comment: True, your example obviously has more utility in this case.  It's one of the few examples I've seen where the long form of String.Format has more utility and is easier to use than the interpolated version.  I was just trying to show other options.

Comment: @Plutonix -thank you for responding, There is one more caveat  attached to it ,the number of columns are also variable.
so the data(0), data(1) string would need to change?

Comment: ` data(0), data(1)...` ***is not*** a string.  It cannot be a string.  It is the code references to the CSV data you read in.  This is intended to work to "map" one input CSV to many different output orders as in the original question.  Since it is driven by the format string created, it could still work with multiple column counts.  But if there are many different input counts, I would probably do it differently to avoid a config file typo from creating an exception.

Comment: @plutonix ,the problem i'm facing is  that the number of columns in the csv files vary. soi need to change the  `data(0), data(1)` argument.
I have tried other approaches but in vain.

Comment: The code above could go up to `data(999)` for a one size fits all solution. It would handle a file with almost any number of elements. The actual order is controlled by the format argument.  It wont crash unless the **format** string references an index which does not exist in the file.  The other answer I gave (and have since deleted since you have gone off on another new dorection), showed how to handle the config and gave a different approach to index the data elements.